# $http.get() fires $locationChangeSuccess event?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, xmlhttprequest

My understanding of [`$http`](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/docs/api/ng/service/$http#usage) is that the service wraps around the browser's XMLHttpRequest to provide async callout capabilities. However, when I use `$http` together with `$location`, I am finding that calling `$http.get()` also fires `$locationChangeSuccess` when the request produces a success response.

Why is this happening? Since the URL in my browser hasn't changed, I'm not expecting the `$locationChangeSuccess` event to be fired. The [controller below](https://jsfiddle.net/vLaxjk5L/1/) illustrates the problem.

```
angular.module('fiddle', [])
  .controller('MainController', ['$scope', '$http', '$location'
    function($scope, $http, $location) {
      $scope.numberOfLocationChanges = 0;

      // Constructor
      $scope.__init__ = function() {            
        $http.get('/').then(
          function success(response) {
            console.log('success: %o', response);
          },
          function error(response) {
            console.log('error: %o', response);
          }
        );
      };

      $scope.handleLocationChangeSuccess = function() {
        $scope.numberOfLocationChanges++;
      };

      // Bind event handlers
      $scope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess',
        $scope.handleLocationChangeSuccess);

      // Call the constructor
      $scope.__init__();
    }
  ]);
```

In case it matters, after removing the `$location` service the `$locationChangeSuccess` is no longer fired.